# Getting a 100 error and I do a Get call with the facebook api

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

I just updated from facebook 2.8 to 2.10. Then I went through and took out all of the fields that have been deprecated. Now that I'm running my code I get a

```
Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{pageid}/insights
  Params:  {'fields': '["ad_id","ad_name","adset_id","adset_name","campaign_id","campaign_name","account_id","account_name","buying_type","relevance_score","spend","reach","impressions","clicks","social_reach","social_impressions","unique_clicks","social_clicks","unique_social_clicks","call_to_action_clicks","inline_link_clicks","unique_inline_link_clicks","inline_post_engagement","objective","total_actions","total_unique_actions"]', 'level': 'ad', 'time_ranges': '[{"since":"2017-08-03","until":"2017-08-03"}]'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
        "code": 100, 
        "type": "GraphMethodException", 
        "fbtrace_id": "AStcsafetT"
      }
    }
```

I have been looking through the api and none of these data types have change. My output in cmd when i run my python script I get:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I'm pretty sure that mean I returning a None back. So I'm returning an empty string?

Thanks

Comment: Does that error go away, if you specify less fields? And what insight _metrics_ are you even asking for here?

Comment: I'm doing that right now, clicks, impressions and spend are the key ones

Comment: It seems that only bringing ad_id still gets that error

Comment: I think I figure it out it has to do with admin access and not finding a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to do with an invalid parameter. An account got deactivated and this error

```
Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
        "code": 100, 
        "type": "GraphMethodException", 
        "fbtrace_id": "AStcsafetT"
      }
    }
```

ment that the account I was trying to find does not exist and nothing is being returned.